# some basic oracle concepts

Tags: oracle11g

Hi:
In our new application we have to use the oracle as the db,and we use mysql/sqlserver before,when I come to oracle I am confused by its concepts,for exmaple,the table space,the object,the schema table,index, procedure, database link,...:(

And the schema is closed to the user,I can not make it.

Since when we use the mysql,I just know that one database contain as many tables,and contain as many users,user have different authentication for different table.

But in oracle,everything is different.

Anyone can tell me some basic concepts of oracle,and some quick start docs?

Comment: You can check for the resources in Oracle site and W3 Schools. Also check askTom articles.
Also i checked this link <http://playwithdb.blogspot.in>..though few blogs..it gives good insight of all basic stuff oracle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oracle has specific meanings for commonly-used terms, and you're right, it is confusing. I'll build a hierarchy of terms from the bottom up:

- **Database** - In Oracle, the database is the collection of files that make up your overall collection of data. To get a handle on what Oracle means, picture the database management system (dbms) in a non-running state. All those files are your "database."
- **Instance** - When you start the Oracle software, all those files become active, things get loaded into memory, and there's an entity to which you can connect. Many people would use the term "database" to describe a running dbms, but, once everything is up-and-running, Oracle calls it an, "instance."
- **Tablespace** - A abstraction that allows you to think about a chunk of storage without worrying about the physical details. When you create a user, you ask Oracle to put that user's data in a specific tablespace. Oracle manages storage via the tablespace metaphor.
- **Data file** - The physical files that actually store the data. Data files are grouped into tablespaces. If you use all the storage you have allocated to a user, or group of users, you add data files (or make the existing files bigger) to the tablespace they're configured to use.
- **User** - An abstraction that encapsulates the privileges, authentication information, and default storage areas for an account that can log on to an Oracle instance.
- **Schema** - The tables, indices, constraints, triggers, etc. that are owned by a particular user. There is a one-to-one correspondence between users and schemas. The schema has the same name as the user. The difference between the two is that the user concept is all about account information, while the schema concept deals with logical database objects.

This is a very simplified list of terms. There are different states of "running" for an Oracle instance, for example, and it's easy to get into very nuanced discussions of what things mean. Here's a practical exercise that will let you put your hands on these things, and will make the distinctions clearer:

1. Start an already-created Oracle instance. This step will transform a group of files, or as Oracle would say, a database, into a running Oracle instance.
2. Create a tablespace with the [CREATE TABLESPACE](http://ss64.com/ora/tablespace_c.html) command. You'll have to specify some data files to put into the tablespace, as well as some storage parameters.
3. Create a user with the [CREATE USER](http://ss64.com/ora/user_c.html) command. You'll see that the items you have to specify have to do with passwords, privileges, quotas, and the like. Specify that the user's data be stored in the tablespace you created in step 2.
4. Connect to the Oracle using the credentials you created with the new user from step 3. Type, "SELECT * FROM CAT". Nothing should come back yet. Your user has a schema, but it's empty.
5. Run a [CREATE TABLE](http://ss64.com/ora/table_c.html) command. [INSERT](http://ss64.com/ora/insert.html) some data into the table. The schema now contains some objects.

Comment: does the "collection of files" mean the "xx.dbf" files? And what is the releathion between the user2tablespace user2schema and user2database. In our application we have storage different datas in different database(instance),for example a database "mbuser" for all user related data,and "mbschool" for all schools and "mbfeatrue" for all features,since the database are exist yet,we do not want to merge them together,so any idea to access these different database in the asp.net application?

Comment: Yes. Those files, and configuration files, logs, and other files. I run the risk of misspeaking or oversimplifying, but I think we could call the files in \\oracle\product\<version>\admin\<INSTANCENAME>, ..\oradata\<INSTANCENAME>, and ..\flash_recovery_area\<INSTANCENAME> as the files that make up the database.  I do not know, if for a certification exam, Oracle would want you to include the "program" files.

Comment: "And what is the releathion between the user2tablespace user2schema and user2database" - A user stores all data and objects in a default tablespace. Every user has a schema, and there's a 1-1 correspondence between the two. A user is one of the accounts associated with a given database/instance.

Comment: So one user will have a default tablespace,can he have access to other tables inder other tablespace?

Comment: "so any idea to access these different database in the asp.net application?" - If you want to keep the instances separate, obtain or create the credentials for users in each of the instances. In the code that manipulates the data, make a separate connection to each instance using those users. Manipulate your data in the program, and send it back to the appropraite back-end instance.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a try and read the docs you provide.

Comment: "So one user will have a default tablespace,can he have access to other tables inder other tablespace?" - Tablespaces are about storage, and users are about privileges. To give a user access to objects owned by another user, in other words, objects in a different schema, you'd GRANT those privileges to the user. For example, you could say, "GRANT SELECT ON OTHER_USER.TABLE1 TO THIS_USER". Look into Oracle ROLES, if you want to manage privileges in a more abstract way.

Answer (score 1):

- table spaces: these are basically
  storage definitions. when defining a
  table or index, etc., you can specify
  storage options simply by putting
  your table in a specific table_space
- table, index, procedure: these are pretty much the same
- user, schema: explained well before
- database link: you can join table A in instance A and table B in instance B using a  - database link between the two instances (while logged in on of them)
- object: has properties (like a columns in a table) and methods that operate on those poperties (pretty much like in OO design); these are not widely used

A few links:

Start page for 11g rel 2 docs http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/homepage

Database concepts, Table of contents http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/toc.htm